# Is this change to Stunning Strike balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, homebrew-review

Does this change to stunning strike make monks too powerful, or is it reasonable?

> Stunning Strike
> Starting at 5th Level, you can interfere with the flow of ki in an opponent's body. When you hit another creature with a melee weapon Attack, you can attempt a Stunning Strike. The target must succeed on a Constitution saving throw or be Stunned until the end of your next turn. **You can use this feature a number of times equal to your monk level. You regain expended uses when you finish a short or long rest.**

The parts in **bold** are the parts that have been edited.

The purpose of this change is to prevent players from feeling like they are wasting a ki point every time they use an ability that is not stunning strike, which is a problem that has been mentioned several times of various message boards.

Comment: Some explanation of why you are making this change (What was wrong with the feature? Why was that a problem? How does this fix that problem?) would greatly improve this question

Comment: So you are keeping the Ki in the flavour, but divorced from the mechanics?

Comment: Please review our guidance for homebrew review questions: [How can I ask a good homebrew review question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8121)

Comment: Balanced relative to what? What are we supposed to compare this to? What does "balanced" mean here?

Answer (score 6):

**You are doubling the effective ki monks have available**

That is a massive buff. I have seen many discussions about which classes are strong where monks are near the bottom of the list, so this might be desirable. However, doubling the resources that they have available is likely too much - consider giving a smaller buff then playtesting.

**This change will likely make monks feel *more* like a stun bot**

You now have a resource dedicated to stunning that you cannot use for anything else, that will be refreshed after a short rest. This means that optimal monk play will involve a *lot* of stunning people. Even if the monk can also use their other abilities more, it won't necessarily achieve the desired feel of a more versatile monk.

**Consider buffing the abilities you want the player to use**

You are currently making the ability that you feel currently dominates monk play and making it better. Instead, consider buffing those other abilities - as an example, doubling the amount of ki wan doubling the cost of stunning strike doesn't change the strength of stunning strike, but does make all those other abilities more appealing, and feel less like a waste.

Comment: The first section here needs expansion, I think. Yes, OK, this makes a monk stronger, but monks are usually considered weak—so _where does this put them?_ That is, effectively, the question that was asked, so leaving that out kinda _doesn’t answer the question_.

Comment: @KRyan Right, which is why some more details from OP are necessary.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov No, it doesn’t mean that at all. This question is perfectly clear—it’s just asking for more than this.

Comment: @KRyan I'm not quite sure what you expect. In my experience with playing monks and participating in discussions about balance/optimisation, I expect this would be too much of a buff, which I say. It's a very simple change, so I can't really say too much more without playtesting (which I believe is too high of a standard to put on homebrew answers).

Rather than just say "no" (which is the answer to the question posed), I expand on why the homebrew also doesn't meet the stated purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the general conundrums of monk players (as a monk player) in improving monks is whether ki points given to the class should be in accordance to either a full caster's or half caster's alternative spell point pool. A half caster has 66 spell points, and a full caster has around 133 (at level 20). With 2 short rests the total ki points currently adds to 60, meaning the monk is supposed to be based around a short rest half caster. It seems like you are asking the same question. Maybe the most simple answer: test out removing the short rest ki point aspect and give monks 60 total ki points although that removes a lot of the flavour of the class. What you can do is give it the same amount of ki points as a 3/4 caster would have; this would be 30 at level 20. As we can see the monk class is arguably more reliant on ki points than half casters are on spell points, I feel like WotC might be more accepting of that increase as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).